# Image outside the page size in altaCV based CV

Tags: pdftex, includegraphics

I'm a beginner in Latex and I'm using [this template](https://github.com/simonalbrecht/curriculum-vitae) as base to go ahead and learn latex in the same process. I'm stuck on one point where my profile image is going outside the bounds of paper on right side. I've tried to search about AltaCV but the method in parent altaCV class isn't working in this customised template.

Preview of the problem:
[image]

The code in altaCV class is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \ifdef{\@photodiameter}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@photodiameter-2em}}{}%
    \raggedright\color{emphasis}%
    {\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
    \medskip
    {\large\bfseries\color{accent}\@tagline\par}
    \medskip
    {\footnotesize\bfseries\@personalinfo\par}
    \ifdef{\@photodiameter}{%
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{\@photodiameter}
    \if@normalphoto
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\@photo}
    \else
      \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={\@photo}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];
    \fi%
    \end{minipage}\par}{}%
  \endgroup\medskip
}
```

I can't seem to find the piece of code which adjusts the position of image. If anyone can help me with this problem, it'd be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm the author of `AltaCV` https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV. What were you trying to change? In most cases you don't need (well, not recommended) to edit the .cls, as the `geometry` page layout options, font packages etc are in the .tex file's preamble. Also I see that the red error balloon is flashing up in your screenshot, next to the "Recompile" button, so it would be best to click on that and see what your error is.

Comment: So as I said it the post, it was actually a CV based on your AltaCV class and author of that project had heavily modified code and kind of in a hackish way. So, I just ditched the idea of using that code and switched to pure AltaCV based files and I'll proceed from there. But here is the error message you requested. https://postimg.cc/m1ybtyr9

Comment: Regarding the other question @LianTze Lim, I wasn't changing anything in the code. I was trying to add `\photo{2cm}{200}` code in the main file but the image kept going outside the page on right side. I think you might be able to find out what is wrong with the project I was using, but since I've ditched it, everything is fine now.